# High PHP APC fragments and hollow usage pie chart

Tags: php, caching, apc, litespeed

I use litespeed webserver and PHP APC.
However i notice there is some strange stats from "apc.php".

[image: APC Stats]

First strange thing is although fragmentation percentage is very low (under 1%), but the number of fragments is very high (6935 fragments).
I have tried to increase the "user_entries_hint" several times, yet the number of fragments still high even though the percentage is very low.

Second strange thing is the "Host status diagrams" has hollow part. When i see other apc.php stats from someone else, i rarely see the hollow part. I wonder if this is related with the fragments number.

I have enough free RAM (more than 50 GB), and i clear the whole APC every 2 hours.

Here is my PHP.ini config

```
apc.enabled = 1
apc.ttl = 0
apc.slam_defense = 0
apc.gc_ttl=3600;
apc.user_ttl = 0
apc.shm_segments = 1
apc.shm_size = 6G
apc.max_file_size = 20M
apc.stat=0
apc.enable_cli = 0
apc.mmap_file_mask="/home/apc_temp/apc.XXXXXX"
apc.user_entries_hint = 360000
apc.num_files_hint = 30000
extension="apc.so"
```

And here is my APC runtime setting.

```
apc.cache_by_default = 1
apc.canonicalize = 1
apc.coredump_unmap = 0
apc.enable_cli = 0
apc.enabled = 1
apc.file_md5 = 0
apc.file_update_protection = 2
apc.filters = 
apc.gc_ttl = 3600
apc.include_once_override = 0
apc.lazy_classes = 0
apc.lazy_functions = 0
apc.max_file_size = 20M
apc.mmap_file_mask = /home/apc_temp/apc.k8kTDm
apc.num_files_hint = 30000
apc.preload_path = 
apc.report_autofilter = 0
apc.rfc1867 = 0
apc.rfc1867_freq = 0
apc.rfc1867_name = APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix = upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl = 3600
apc.serializer = default
apc.shm_segments = 1
apc.shm_size = 6G
apc.slam_defense = 0
apc.stat = 0
apc.stat_ctime = 0
apc.ttl = 0
apc.use_request_time = 1
apc.user_entries_hint = 360000
apc.user_ttl = 0
apc.write_lock = 1
```

Thank you.